# Force a specific cell type when importing data from Google sheets with gspread and gspread_dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm using `gspread_dataframe` to import data from Google Sheets. I'd like to **force all imported data to strings** independently of the cell type used in the worksheet.

Reading the gspread_dataframe [documentation](https://github.com/robin900/gspread-dataframe) I noticed I can use all the options supported by the Pandas text parsing readers ([such as this one](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)). In theory `dtype=str` or `dtype="string"` should force all values to be imported with that specific  type. Somehow the data gets interpreted during the import.

In the scenario below the imported dataframe has decimals dropped due to the fact that all `Amounts` are in `number` format in the worksheet.

Can I force `gspread_dataframe` to import every charachter in the cell as is, not interpreting the number data (no decimals dropped along the way)?

```
import gspread
import gspread_dataframe as gsframe

gsframe.get_as_dataframe(
    worksheet=sheet, 
    header=0, 
    dtype=str, 
    usecols=cols, 
    skiprows=row_offset,
    skip_blank_lines=True).dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all').fillna('')
```

```
 Google Sheets           Imported Dataframe 
string  numbers           string    string          

Name    Amount              Name    Amount    <-- All decimals dropped
A      -25.00               A      -25
B       63.00               B       63
C       20.00               C       20
D      -10.00               D      -10
```

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
gsframe.get_as_dataframe(
    worksheet=sheet, 
    header=0, 
    dtype=str, 
    usecols=cols, 
    skiprows=row_offset,
    skip_blank_lines=True).dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all').fillna('')
```

#### To:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(sheet.get_all_values())
```

- When I tested your sample value of the Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

  ```
    Name  Amount
       A  -25.00
       B   63.00
       C   20.00
       D  -10.00
  ```

#### Note:

- When your script is used, the result that `dtype=str,` was removed is the result you expect?